# Can we further simplify this MySQL query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table  in MySQL with following fields. 
Date, block_no, entity, reading

Now I am firing this SQL and getting the results.

```
SELECT DATE,block_no, 
SUM(IF(entity='KS',READING,0)) AS KS,
SUM(IF(entity='KB',READING,0)) AS KB,
SUM(IF(entity='V1',READING,0)) AS V1,
(SUM(IF(entity='KS',READING,0)) + SUM(IF(entity='KB',READING,0)))/SUM(IF(entity='V1',READING,0)) AS "New Rate"
FROM dbf_sdl
GROUP BY DATE,block_no;
```

This is a  simple query with three entities and calculated field, but I have to write the queries which involves upto 15 entities and some calculated fields using them. Is there a way by which these queries can be simplified further? the field alias is not allowed for calculations like I can't use

```
(KS+KB)/V1 AS "New Rate"
```

Kindly suggest.
Thanks

Answer (score 7):

The column alias is not available for use in the same SELECT statement, but if you do not want to rewrite the calculations then you can use a subquery:

```
select DATE,block_no, KS, KB, V1,
    (KS+KB)/V1 AS "New Rate"
from
(
    SELECT DATE,block_no, 
    SUM(IF(entity='KS',READING,0)) AS KS,
    SUM(IF(entity='KB',READING,0)) AS KB,
    SUM(IF(entity='V1',READING,0)) AS V1
    FROM dbf_sdl
    GROUP BY DATE,block_no
) d
```

Answer (score 2):

You can aggregate in a subquery to avoid repeating the SUM():

```
SELECT *,(KS+KB)/V1 AS "New Rate"
FROM (SELECT DATE,block_no, 
      SUM(IF(entity='KS',READING,0)) AS KS,
      SUM(IF(entity='KB',READING,0)) AS KB,
      SUM(IF(entity='V1',READING,0)) AS V1,
      FROM dbf_sdl
      GROUP BY DATE,block_no
      )as Sub;
```