# Can regular expression solve this ? How can we get an array of parameters used in an expression?

Tags: mysql, regex

I am passing a expression to a MySQL query mentioned in question - [Can we further simplify this MySQL query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17175113/can-we-further-simplify-this-mysql-query)

I want to extract the variable names form the expression passed so that I can generate the SQL dynamically.
For Eg. consider following expression as input.

`(PA+KS)-(RR+DFS)/(DF*LK)`

How can we get an array of parameters used in above expression ... I mean an output like this
`('PA','KS','RR','DFS','DF','LK')`

Can regular expression help ?

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I used above PHP code to extract the parameter names.

```
$s=array('+','-','(',')','*','/');
$a="(AB+DP)-(RE*PQR)/KBS";
$a=str_ireplace($s,",",$a);
echo $a;
$a = preg_replace( '/,+/', ',', $a ); //replacing extra commas
print_r(explode(",",$a));
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is the only thing you parse (math operators and capital letters variables), then yes. You can just scan for `[A-Z]+` and you'll get your variables.

If you need anything more complicated, I'd go with a proper tokeniser. It's not hard to implement and most languages have some kind of support for `flex` or similar utilities.

Comment: Thanks for your response, Can you please regexp for using it in PHP .... I have no idea about it ?